# Angular 9 Application Not running on IE11

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11, browser-support

Our team has created an angular 9 new project and it is working perfectly fine on Google Chrome and Firefox but on IE11 I cant see anything.
I have tried everything on from the internet followed every blog related to this but I unable to achieve the goal.

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
      "@modules/*": ["src/app/modules/*"],
      "@services/*": ["src/app/services/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["src/app/shared/*"],
      "@env/*": ["src/environments/*"],
      "@mocks/*": ["mocks/*"],
      "@models/*": ["src/app/models/*"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

tsconfig-es5.app.json

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5" 
     }
   }
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "connect-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 6574",
    "start:dev": "concurrently \"npm run mocks\" \"npm start\"",
    "mocks": "json-server --watch db.json --routes db.routes.json --port 6575",
    "build": "ng build --base-href /ng/",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6576",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngx-gallery/core": "^5.0.0-beta.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/zingchart": "^2.8.0",
    "angular-gridster2": "^9.1.0",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "flatpickr": "^4.6.3",
    "json-server": "^0.16.1",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "ng2-flatpickr": "^9.0.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "shortcut-buttons-flatpickr": "^0.3.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zingchart": "^2.9.0",
    "zingchart-angular": "0.0.6",
    "zinggrid": "^1.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.3",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-notes": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/angular": "^5.3.19",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "ember-cli-cors": "0.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

I have followed this link https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-fix-your-angular-app-when-its-not-working-in-ie11-eb24cb6d9920

Also I have seen for others in the posts that they had some error in their console of IE11 but there is no as such any error in my Console window of IE11.
Please check this screenshot of IE11.
[image]

[image]

pollyfills.ts

```
/***************************************************************************************************
 * Load `$localize` onto the global scope - used if i18n tags appear in Angular templates.
 */
import '@angular/localize/init';
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */






/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
 import 'classlist.js';  //Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.


 import 'core-js/es6/reflect';



/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 */
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 * because those flags need to be set before `zone.js` being loaded, and webpack
 * will put import in the top of bundle, so user need to create a separate file
 * in this directory (for example: zone-flags.ts), and put the following flags
 * into that file, and then add the following code before importing zone.js.
 * import './zone-flags';
 *
 * The flags allowed in zone-flags.ts are listed here.
 *
 * The following flags will work for all browsers.
 *
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 * (window as any).__zone_symbol__UNPATCHED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames
 *
 *  in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 *  with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 *
 *  (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
 *
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.


/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
```

---------------EDIT--------------------

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the `pollyfills.js`? There's some IE-specific stuff in there that you may want to uncomment.

Comment: @mwilson that I have already uncommented..

Comment: Anything strange in the network tab?

Comment: I have edited my question and have added the network tab and pollyfils.ts

Comment: As I can see in your polyfills.js file, you have added the import for @angular/localize/init, which does not support for the IE11 browser as this function uses 'let' and 'const' to define the function. Remove the import of localize from your polyfills.js file and you can run your project in IE11 browser.

Answer (score 8):

Have you edited the **browserslist** file? You should remove `not` before `IE 9-11`. The browserslist is like below:

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

I also made a new angular 9 app and it can work well in IE 11. I added a new **tsconfig-es5.app.json** file, updated **angular.json** configuration, edited **browserslist** then run `ng serve --configuration es5`. The result is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D7AG.png). Besides, you don't need to uncomment in **polyfills.ts**.

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular9",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have edit the browserlist as well and I too made the tsconfig.app.json where I gave the es5 as configuration in order support js on IE  also added the Meta tag but still no luck.

Comment: Please don't uncomment the polyfills in `polyfills.ts`. I tried that if I uncomment them and install the packages, it won't load in IE. Then you could clear IE cache and try again.

Comment: you mean to say I should comment out again the classlist.js and web-animations-js?

Comment: Yes, you could try to restore the `polyfills.ts` to its original state. In my `polyfills.ts`, there's only this line `import 'zone.js/dist/zone';` uncommented. As far as I know, Angular 8+ doesn't need to uncomment `polyfills.ts` to make it compatible with IE.

Comment: I have done that. Now I'm getting some errors in IE. I have edited my question and added the images

Comment: It seems that your Angular app is not a new blank app. The issue seems not related to the configuration but some syntax not compatible with IE. I suggest you to provide a reproducibe sample through online code editor like [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or something so that we can have a test and see where the issue is.

Comment: Thanks @YuZhou along with `es5 tsconfig file` I had to also install core-js in order to run on IE11.  `npm i -S core-js` and in the polyfills.js I add this line `import 'core-js';` then it worked.

Answer (score 7):

Modifying the below two things will make it work (tested on both Angular 8 & 9 version).

- In **browserslist** file, change `not IE 9-11` -> **`IE 9-11`**
- In **tsconfig.json** file, change `"target": "es2015"` -> **`"target": "es5"`**

Mostly, the above changes suffice. If you still get some error (may be due to more complex UI/UX), you can try modify the **polyfills.ts** file,

- Uncomment `// import 'classlist.js';` and `// import 'web-animations-js';`
- Must `npm install --save classlist.js web-animations-js`

Answer (score 2):

Please remove below line from your polyfills.js file.

```
**/***************************************************************************************************
 * Load `$localize` onto the global scope - used if i18n tags appear in Angular templates.
 */
import '@angular/localize/init';**
```

And it will work fine in IE11 browser as well. As I have gone through some documentation it says that, localize is not compatible with es5.

Answer (score 0):

if issue not resolved still, here is the steps

1. browserlists.ts (uncomment IE11)
2. tsconfig.ts (in target as "es5" and add in lib: "es5")
   "target": "es5",
   "lib": [
   "es2018",
   "es5",
   "dom"
   ]

once done, ng build again before ng serve

Answer (score 0):

1.Add a property like below in `angular.json` file inside projects > architect > build:

```
"es5BrowserSupport": true
```

2.Change your target from  `"target": "es2015"` to  `"target": "es5"` in `tsconfig.json` file

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `polyfills.ts` file and find the import statements commented out under the section `/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. */`:

```
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
```

Uncomment the above import to have your app working with those IE browsers but don't forget to run the following command.

```
npm install --save classlist.js
```

You might be also required to uncomment the following import:

```
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
```

And not to forget to run the following command:

```
npm install --save web-animations-js
```

If the above process does not work then you may do the following and check if it works:)

In `browserslist` file, you may replace `not IE 9-11` with `IE 9-11`.

Also, in `tsconfig.json` file, you may replace `"target": "es2015"` (or whatever) with `"target": "es5"`.

Answer (score -1):

Put below code to index.html file inside of head tag (projectName/src/index.html) and Rerun your application (`ng serve`)

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />